# Manually specifying candidate masters in Maxscale

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, failover, maxscale

Looking over the documentation, I haven't quite been able to find if its possible to manually set the candidate master status of a server in Maxscale.  The reason I am looking for this is because some of the slaves we have hooked up the the master/slave server architecture have inferior hardware to the others, and we don't want them to become the master.  Looking at the documentation, it is possible to set the status of a sever as master or slave, but not specify that we don't want it to become a master.

Is there a setting to do this in Maxscale?  Possibly in maxadmin or a .cnf file or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but at least with recent versions of MaxScale (23.08 in my case) you can use the [servers_no_promotion](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-2308-mariadb-monitor/#servers_no_promotion) parameter in the monitor definition section of the configuration file.

> This is a comma-separated list of server names that will not be chosen
> for primary promotion during a failover or autoselected for
> switchover.

For example

```
servers_no_promotion=slow_server1,slow_server2
```

Answer (score 0):

@klutt points to the correct direction but note that the priority and use_priority parameters only work for a Galera cluster.
Some elaborations here:

Edit `/etc/maxscale.cnf`

1. Assign priority to servers. With the lowest number being the highest priority. But not `0`, which means the lowest priority. Servers with priority number smaller than 0 will never be picked as the master.

```
[server1]
#master node
type=server
address=192.168.0.1
port=3306
priority=1

[server2]
type=server
address=192.168.0.2
port=3306
priority=2

[server3]
type=server
address=192.168.0.3
port=3306
priority=3
```

2. Under monitor block, add `use_priority=true` and `disable_master_role_setting=false`

```
[MariaDB-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=galeramon
servers=server1,server2,server3
user=%username%
password=%password%
monitor_interval=4s
use_priority=true
disable_master_role_setting=false
```

3. Restart maxscale by running `systemctl restart maxscale` and `server1` which has the highest priority, will be the default master.

Answer (score -1):

You can use priorities as described here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale/maxscale-galera-monitor/

Comment: Please add a little explanation to help other users to understand what the link will do.  A couple of helpful points will assist future readers.